# How to remove first paragraph of content in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing

I have got field in database with `<p>intro content</p><p>rest of content....</p>`

How to remove first paragraph of content `<p>intro content</p>` using PHP?

Comment: assuming you have a string, why not just parse the string for the first instance of "</p>" ?

Comment: Take a look at [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Isn't there a fast a simple solution?

Comment: look at Dagon's answer... or you can just query the database and then parse the result with a php function.. int index = strpos($result,"</p>");

Comment: related: [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming mysql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(content_field, '</p>', 1) as cut from TABLE
```

replace in db:

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],SUBSTRING_INDEX([field_name], '</p>', 1),'');
```

Comment: But it will just select, but how to remove?

Comment: [***NO*** Do not use RegEx to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why are you assuming it's in a database?

Comment: Yes, but I have got it also as string before saving. In there a way to parse it before saving?

Comment: well im now confused as to what you want.

Comment: This will fail for everything non-trivial and you will most likely end up with broken markup, consider `<p><p>x</p></p>`

Comment: The solution mentioned in MySQL is fine, but if possible to do it before saving to database then it would be even better.

Comment: @Newbie1 No it is not fine, as mentioned in my comment above. You should use a DOM parser like I wrote in my answer and PLB in the question comment.

Comment: OK, Thanks I will try to fix it based on your comments. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM parser. Maybe [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). You can then select the first element from the DOM and remove it

**Pseudo** Code:

```
$dom->firstChild()->remove();
```